# density of measures

Tags: measure-theory, density-function

Does it generally hold, that given a measure $\nu$ with density $f$ with respect to $\mu$, $\nu = f \cdot \mu $, then the density $f$ must be an $\mathcal{M}^+$-function?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{M}^+$-function, for those unfamiliar with the subject? Plus shouldn't it be $\nu=fd\mu$?

Comment: Oh sorry - $ \mathcal{M}^+$: family of measurable and positive functions. Im unsure of the general notation, but I mean: $ \nu = f \cdot \mu = \int f \text{d} \mu$

Comment: Are you assuming that both measures are sigma-finite and positive? If so then the answer must be yes.